# Windows x64 ABI. How can debugger show you arguments passed to functions

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit, reverse-engineering, abi

In x86 calling conventions parameters are passed on the stack and when using base pointers in a frame it is possible to reconstruct from a call stack what parameters have been passed to successive stack functions (actually the process is done in reverse order from last functioned called going back)

How can we do the same in x64 ABI considering (as per [x64 ABI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t169e9c.aspx)) that registers used for parameter passing RCX, RDX, R8, R9 -> are all volatile and thus loose their values between frames (with no stack backup). ?

Comment: The x64 abi on Windows includes the "parameter area", the stack backup you assumed does not exist.  Navigate to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew5tede7.aspx).  Quote: "This area also provides a convenient place to save register arguments during thunk execution and as a debugging option (for example, it makes the arguments easy to find during debugging if they are stored at their home addresses in the prolog code)"

Comment: @HansPassant There is a backup area indeed, but don't know if optimization could not remove that (just as frame base pointer optimization could take place in x86). If that happens I would assume that even with all debug information present stack reconstruction could not take place at all ?

Comment: @HansPassant Please include that comment as  an answer to be eligible to a proper response marking. +1 for now

Comment: Just link soup.  We're trying to not duplicate anything that's already documented by a 1st party.

Comment: @Flexo So a tentative "link answer" was deleted. Should this question be left as it is then :-) ?